# Calculating $A_{n}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm a beginner in Group theory, and I'm Trying to calculate $A_{4}$, but I couldn't.

I know that this is the subgroup of even permutations in $S_{n}$.

How I can calculate it's all elements?

How I can calculate the all elements of $A_{n}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the definition of an even permutation?

Comment: Which is the meaning of "calculating elements"? (You may also want to enclose the mathematical parts between dollars, so `A_4` would become `$A_4$`, which looks like $A_4$.)

Comment: For $A_4$ it suffices to simply list them out.  There aren't many and this can be done by brute force listing of all of the elements of $S_4$ and keeping only those who are even.  For $A_n$ in general, it is not useful to actually list them out.  It is far more useful to talk about it with set builder notation or come up with a set of generators for the set or more generally just be able to recognize whether or not a specified permutation is an element of $A_4$.

Comment: I know that an even permutation is a permutation that can be write as an even composition of two-cycles. I tried to write those compositions, but I don't know what is the even limit of possible number of these cycles, how I can differentiate them... In general, there is a useful theorem to do this?

Comment: As for the list of elements in $A_4$, there are $4!/2 = 12$ such elements.  They can be found listed [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_alternating_group:A4) with the table giving various formats for how to represent each.

Comment: Figure out a procedure to determine whether a permutation is even or odd, and apply it to all $4!$ members of $S_4$. As a hint, you might want to use cyclic decompositions. When is a cycle even or odd?

Comment: A cycle is even if it has even elements. A even cycle is an even permutation?

Comment: No.  A permutation is an even permutation if and only if it has an even number of even length cycles in its disjoint cyclic decomposition.  A permutation is an odd permutation if and only if it has an odd number of even length cycles in its disjoint cyclic decomposition.  [Read more about this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation).  An almost immediately obvious counterexample to your claim is the permutation $(1,2)$ which has an odd number of transpositions (*and an odd number of even-length cycles*) and so is odd despite being an even length cycle.

Comment: Oh, this is useful. I had this definition: A even permutation is a permutation that can be write as an even compositions of 2-cycles; is it wrong?

Comment: That definition is also correct and the two definitions can be shown to be equivalent.  A proof of which is included in the wiki post I already linked.

Comment: Thanks you! This is very useful

Comment: Generally, we can write the transposition (i i+d) on the set {1,...,i,...,i+d,...} as the composition of 2d-1 adjacent transpositions by recursion on d:

*The base case is trivial.
*In the recursive case, first rewrite (i, i+d) as (i, i+1) (i+1, i+d) (i, i+1). Then recursively rewrite (i+1, i+d) as adjacent transpositions.                                      
             How this recursion is on d? It seems to be on i, can you give me a explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The group $S_4$ consists of permutations with these cyclic structures:

1. $(1)(1)(1)(1)$- the identity permutation, even.
2. $(2)(1)(1)$ - an involution, odd
3. $(2)(2)$ - even
4. $(3)(1)$ - even
5. $(4)$ - odd.

So permutations with cycle structure $(1)(1)(1)(1),(2)(2)$ or $(3)(1)$ form $A_4$.

In general, in $S_n$, for a permutation with cycle structure $(k_1)...(k_p)$ to see if this permutation is even or odd you need to look at the parity of the sum $(k_1-1)+(k_2-1)+...+(k_p-1)$.

Comment: Does (1) denote a 1-cycle?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

There are only $12$ elements.  There are $8$ three cycles:  $(123),(132),(124),(142),(234),(243),(134),(143)$.  That leaves three, if we throw in the identity. They are $(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)$.

Recall, an odd cycle is even and an even cycle is odd.  Even means the permutation can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions ($2$-cycles).

Answer (score -1):

One concrete way is to consider $S_4$ as the $4\times 4$ permutation matrices (every row/column has exactly one nonzero entry which is equal to one).  Then $A_4$ is the kernel of the determinant map $\det:S_4\to\{\pm1\}$ (i.e. the permutation matrices with determinant 1).